# Magento 2.2.7 cron job issue finished without completed

Tags: magento2, cron

We have added the following lines to the crontab file to run magento cron after every 1 minute.

```
* * * * * /bin/php -c /etc/php.ini /home/centos/public_html/staging/bin/magento cron:run > /home/centos/public_html/staging/var/log/magento.cron.log&

* * * * * /bin/php -c /etc/php.ini /home/centos/public_html/staging/update/cron.php > /home/centos/public_html/staging/var/log/update.cron.log&

* * * * * /bin/php -c /etc/php.ini /home/centos/public_html/staging/bin/magento setup:cron:run > /home/centos/public_html/staging/var/log/setup.cron.log&
```

We have created cron job for our module under magento default group which is to be executed after every 30 minutes.

```
<job name="auto_review_email" instance="MyCompany\ModuleName\Cron\AutoReviewEmail" method="execute">
    <schedule>*/30 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

But when we check in cron_schedule table and in our logs, cron job finished after 1 minute without executing completely. Please refer to below screenshot:-

[image]

We have tried using flock in crontab, checked the server timings but nothing worked.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Refer to the link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261722/magento-2-need-cronjob-output and create a controller where you can debug your cron. From the look of this, cron scheduling not have any issue, your cron is completing in a second, so you need to debug your script to resolve this issue

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Munir Yes, It was issue with script. Thanks

Comment: Do I convert it in answer? so that it will helpful for others in future