# Magento 2 - Test cronjob from browser

Tags: magento2, testing, cronjobs

I have created a cronjob in:

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Cron/MyCron.php
```

It's in development phase, so every time I need to check the data or debug anything I am creating a log file and rescheduling it to run cron.

My question is, is there any way to run cron from browser? so that I can test it instantly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you working in local environment ?

Comment: Reference =>  https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/secy/secy-cron.html

Comment: Check this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261722/magento-2-need-cronjob-output/261732#261732

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can test your cron on browser.

Create a model in you module

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/YourModel.php
```

add a function

```
public function doStuff()
{
    //Add cronjob code here
}
```

Now move all the code of your cron in this function `doStuff()`.
Create frontend contorller

```
app/code/Vendor/Module/Index/MyController.php
```

in `execute` function call your model function

```
$this->model->doStuff();
```

where `$this->model` is the object of your model.
now you can test your code through controller.

After your work is done, call the same model function in your cron

That should work :)

Answer (score 7):

You may follow the steps below to test a cron job from browser.

**Step 1)**

Create a PHP file names "**cronLaunch.php**" under your project root directory

FIle: **cronLaunch.php**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

//require '../../app/bootstrap.php';
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' && isset($_GET['job'])) {
    define('CRONJOBCLASS', $_GET['job']);
} elseif (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
    die('Please add the class of the cron job you want to execute as a job parameter (?job=Vendor\Module\Class)');
} elseif (!isset($argv[1])) {
    die('Please add the class of the cron job you want to execute enclosed IN DOUBLE QUOTES as a parameter.' . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    define('CRONJOBCLASS', $argv[1]);
}

class CronRunner extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state,\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response)
    {
        $this->_response = $response;
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    }

    function launch()
    {
        $cron = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->create(CRONJOBCLASS);

        $cron->execute();
        return $this->_response;
    }
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('CronRunner');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

**step 2)**

Open browser and text the cron job

I assume you your cron class file is `MyVendor/MyModule/Cron/CronClass.php`

so enter the following URL in your browser and test your cron file.

```
http://localhost/YOURMAGENTOPROJECT/cronLaunch.php?job=MyVendor\MyModule\Cron\CronClass
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use n98-magerun2 https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2
. After you give the n98-magerun2.phar execute permission you could run

Get all available cron job list.

```
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:list
```

To run you specific cron

```
./n98-magerun2.phar sys:cron:run your_cron_job_code
```

Comment: I use it all the time, very easy and quick, better than browser

Comment: Good answer.  Just installed it, ran my cron job and found the error, all in a few minutes.

Comment: this is a good answer and very appropriate solution for runnign the cron jobs locally to test and develop

Answer (score 0):

I have done some modification previously example for choice method in class

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

//require '../../app/bootstrap.php';

if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' && isset($_GET['job'])) {
    define('CRONJOBCLASS', $_GET['job']);
} elseif (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
    die('Please add the class of the cron job you want to execute as a job parameter (?job=Vendor\Module\Class)');
} elseif (!isset($argv[1])) {
    die('Please add the class of the cron job you want to execute enclosed IN DOUBLE QUOTES as a parameter.' . PHP_EOL);
} else {
    define('CRONJOBCLASS', $argv[1]);
}

$method = (isset($_GET['method']))? $_GET['method'] : 'execute';
define('CRONJOBMETHOD', $method);

class CronRunner extends \Magento\Framework\App\Http
    implements \Magento\Framework\AppInterface
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state, \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $response)
    {
        $this->_response = $response;
        $state->setAreaCode('adminhtml');
    }

    function launch()
    {
        $cron = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->create(CRONJOBCLASS);

        $cron->{CRONJOBMETHOD}();
        return $this->_response;
    }
}

$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('CronRunner');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

and URL like that

```
http://your-host/cronLaunch.php?job=MyVendor\MyModule\Cron\CronClass&method=YourMethod
```